# Pop all the pages except first page BlackBerry 10 Cascades?

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

How to pop all the pushed pages except first page in BlackBerry 10 qml?

Comment: As Richard suggested, you can use the navigateTo method to do so.
navigationPane.navigateTo(navigationPane.at(0))
According to documentation, any pages above the one navigated to in the stack will be removed from the stack

Answer (score 5):

That may depend on the base object. When using the NavigationPane for example I would use the navigatTo(Page *targetPage) method and specify the first page as the target.